# Вопрос о htaccess

Tags: редирект, .htaccess

Здраствуйте.
Есть ли возможность сделать с http://site.ru/blabla 302 редирект на http://site.ru/search/blabla

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.{3,256})$ http://site.ru/search/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.{2,128})$ search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Но работает не корректно.
Почемуто в url так http://site.ru/search/search/search/....
И местами менял и сам код тестировал но никак.
Просьба подсказать.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте последнюю строчку переставить на место третьей и подправить в ней регулярное выражение. Примерно так:

```
RewriteRule ^/search/(.{2,128})$ /search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.{3,256})$ /search$1 [R=302,L]
```

К тому же домен можно не указывать и после search слеш не нужен (он придет из регулярки).

Или вариант номер 2: перед третьей строкой добавить

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search/*$
```

Но регулярку в четвертой строке все равно исправить надо

Answer (score 1):

У Вас стоит флаг L в третьей строке. Это говорит о том, что это последнее правило, и дальше директива RewriteRule выполняться не будет. Т.е. Я себе вижу это примерно так:

1. Идет запрос http://site.ru/blabla
2. Происходит замена на http://site.ru/search/blabla
3. Работа .htaccess заканчивается.
4. Идет запрос http://site.ru/search/blabla
5. Происходит замена на http://site.ru/search/search/blabla
6. и т.д.

Попробуйте убрать флаг L в третьей строчке, ну или покопать в эту сторону...
Ну и замените 301 на 302...